# is there a way to make a telepot bot read messages from other bots?

Tags: python, telegram, telepot

I am developing a telegram bot using the telepot library for python and needed to have two bots communicate with each other in a group.
for some reason, neither bot cannot read messages sent by bots.

can someone tell me how i could do ?

here are the bots settings:

```
Privacy mode = OFF
Group privacy = OFF
Allow groups = ON
```

Thank you.

Comment: convert the group to super group && make both bots admin

Comment: @AlenPaulVarghese it was the first thing I did, but nothing,

Comment: use user account then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you'll never be able to let two bots communicate on the same group.

though, they can communicate -not on a group- using a different approach which is a channel.

bots can read all channel's messages, hence you can make both of your bots read each other's messages by sending it on the same channel.
for more information, check this out [what messages will my bot get](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#what-messages-will-my-bot-get)